# Fancybox data-source not working after page 2 of datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, fancybox

It's bug or ... am I dumb?

For starters, I'm writing some PHP code using jQuery datatables and fancyapps. And I'm creating some buttons on datatables row with the id from that row. The code is too long with many js/css extension, so here the code pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RXpREY

All the link is working for fancyapp, but why the [detail] button from page 2-3 of the datatables not working? it's start in this code

```
<td>
    <a data-fancybox2 data-type="iframe" href="javascript:;" data-src="detail.php?id=15" class="smallbutton">Detail</a> <a class="smallbutton" data-fancybox data-type="iframe" href="javascript:;" data-src="edit.php?id=15">Edit</a> 
    <a class="smallbutton" href="delete.php?id=15">Delete</a> 
</td>
```

What more strange is, the [edit] button from all the page is working. Is there something I am missing? I feel really dumb because of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fancybox is initialized through delegation using the `[data-fancybox]` attribute by default which is why your edit link is working regardless of table redraws.

However, you'll notice that your settings do not persist for the edit link, which is your first clue.

You want to initialize Fancybox each time the table is drawn/redrawn.

```
table.on('draw', function() {
  $('[data-fancybox]', this).fancybox({
    toolbar: false,
    smallBtn: true,
    iframe: {
      preload: false,
      css: {
        width: '600px'
      }
    },
    afterClose: function() {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
  $('[data-fancybox2]', this).fancybox({
    width: 600,
    toolbar: false,
    smallBtn: true,
    iframe: {
      preload: false
    }
  });
})
```

As per [this updated example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/voJeLv).

Comment: it's working!!! thank you. But i still confused, so i must using draw function when using 2 or more data-fancybox ?

Comment: Fancybox isn't initialised on dom elements that are mutated unless you programatically initialise the library when the dom changes, which is what this answer implies.

Answer (score 2):

When you are initializing fancybox using `$(something).fancybox()`, you are applying custom options for items that are currently existing on the page. For items that will exist in the future, you have to initialize again after they appear in the DOM or use `selector` option (see http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage), example:

```
$().fancybox({
    selector : '[data-fancybox]',
    toolbar: false,
    smallBtn: true,
    iframe: {
        preload: false,
        css : {
            width: '600px'
        }
    }, 
    afterClose : function() { 
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```